# Как правильно вывести данные с JSON - PHP на таблицу?

Tags: php, json, table

Имеются данные в формате JSON, делаю вывод посредством foreach но получается вывести только опр-таблицу, как пройтись по всему JSON и вывести данные в таблицу?

```
$json = '{
  "took" : 2,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
    },
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "article-2021",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_score" : 1.5603,
        "_source" : {
          "device" : "19",
          "readingReason" : "1",
          "value" : 890,
          "status" : [ ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "article-2021",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_score" : 2.05,
        "_source" : {
          "device" : "105",
          "readingReason" : "1",
          "value" : 32.4,
          "status" : [ ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}';
```

как вывести посредством php, данные "device" и "value" в таблицу html?

типо:
19 | 890
105 | 32,4

Comment: кто такая опр-таблица? И чем отличается вывод её от вывода любой другой?

Comment: для начала декодируй из json в массив, а потом перебирай $json['hits']['hits']

Comment: до двойного hits сделано, но вот при обращении к _source получается обратиться как [2] или любое другое значение исходя их чего данные выводятся посредством foreach некорректно