# Как вывести данные массива JSON/PHP в необходимом порядке?

Tags: php, массивы, json, foreach

Имеется пустая страничка с поиском и выводом данных в таблицу, данные берутся из переменного $json:

```
$json = '{
  "took" : 4,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
    },
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "article-2021",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_source" : {
          "rnumber" : "1.0",
          "value" : "113",
        }
      }      {
        "_index" : "article-2021",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_source" : {
          "rnumber" : "1.2",
          "value" : "118",
        }
      }      {
        "_index" : "article-2021",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_source" : {
          "rnumber" : "1.2",
          "value" : "13",
        }
      }      {
        "_index" : "article-2021",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_source" : {
          "rnumber" : "1.0",
          "value" : "13",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}';

$array = json_decode($json,true);
```

вывожу данные посредством foreach, при выводе в таблицу html получаю следующий результат:
rnumber: 1,0;
rnumber: 1,2;
rnumber: 1,2;
rnumber: 1,0;

Как вывести в необходимом порядке:
rnumber: 1,0;
rnumber: 1,2;
rnumber: 1,0
rnumber: 1,2

то есть первое данные по 1,0 второе данные по 1,2 и так по порядку. Пожалуйста помогите решить невозможное. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно вывести данные с JSON - PHP на таблицу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1288065/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-json-php-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83)

Comment: нет это другой вопрос

Comment: какая логика в этой последовательности?

Comment: Зачем делать сортировку на php, если это может всё тот же (судя по json...) elasticsearch?

Comment: Приведите код `foreach` для вывода, но в общем случае вам нужно сортировать данные для вывода, добавьте функцию сортировки: `function sort_value($a, $b) {if ($a['rnumber'] > $b['rnumber']) return 1;}` и внутри `foreach` сортируйте для вывода `usort($allrow, 'sort_value');` просто как называются ваши переменные я не знаю